# JFreeChart, JRChartCustomizer, drawing a overlaying rectangle

Tags: jfreechart

I wish to add a rectangle in my chart by extending JRChartCustomizer class.

[image: not a busy cat]

I tried

```
    BufferedImage image = chart.createBufferedImage(20, 20);
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(1, 1, 5, 5));

    chart.draw(g2, new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20));
```

but doesnt work.

Comment: Try  `org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYShapeAnnotation`.

Comment: Some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20XYShapeAnnotation).

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117435).

Comment: It has been solved in the link posted by @trashgod in the previous comment. I am the one who posted the question in the link =D.

Comment: @FailedMathematician: I inked this question to one featuring `XYBoxAnnotation`.